# Background-size issue in webkit mobile

Tags: css, mobile, webkit, background-image

I'm using these rules and looks fine on desktop and firefox mobile:

```
body{
    background: url(../img/home-background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But on mobile webkit browsers (safari and chrome), the image appears wrong, with zoom.

[image: mobile chrome]
[image: mobile firefox]

Comment: post an image what do you mean by 'wrong'?

Comment: is your body 100% of the device width and 100% of the device height? give a fiddle maybe there's another error in the code

Comment: @RachelGallen I post images from Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes probably from the fixed position on your background image. It's a common issue on Sarafi mobile.